# How to get custom header in bash

Tags: bash, curl, http-headers, wget

I'm adding a custom header in Asp.Net app:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Date", DateTime.Now.ToString());
context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
```

When I'm using Fiddler I can see the "X-Date" header in the response.
I need to receive it by using bash.
I tried `curl -i https://my.site.com` and also `wget -O - -o /dev/null --save-headers https://my.site.com` with no success.
In both cases I see just the regular headers like: Content-Type, Server, Date, etc...

How I can receive the "X-Date" header?

Thanks,
Lev

Answer (score 0):

protocol headers are different than file-headers (like http-header and tcp-header are different). When you create a protocol header you wiil need a server to resolve it and use the associated enviroment variables. Example ...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Apache - CGI 
echo "text/plain"
echo ""
echo "$CONTENT_TYPE"
echo "$HTTP_ACCEPT"
echo "$SERVER_PROTOCOL"
```

When calling this script via web, The response ony my browser was...

```
text/html
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP/1.1
```

What you looking for are **enviorment variables** called `$HTTP_ACCEPT`, `$CONTENT_TYPE` and maybe `$SERVER_PROTOCOL` too.